# How do I handle input string was not in correct format

Tags: c#, wpf, exception, tryparse

I am trying to handle an exception but I'm confused about how I do it. Here is my code

```
modules.Add(new Modules() { 
name = namebox.Text, 
code = codebox.Text, 
credits = Convert.ToInt32(creditbox.Text), 
hours = Convert.ToInt32(hoursbox.Text),
date = semesterbox.Text, 
weeks = Convert.ToInt32(semesterweekbox.Text), 
studyhours = m1.Calculations(Convert.ToInt32(hoursbox.Text), Convert.ToInt32(semesterweekbox.Text), Convert.ToInt32(creditbox.Text))
});
```

I'm trying to handle this exception so it does end my code if I do not input values in the textboxes. From the research I've done, I found out that the ToInt32 line might be the issue. Some coders suggested I use the tryparse function. How would I use that function to handle this error?

[image: Exception Thrown]

Comment: can you post the exception as well, that will help a lot.

Comment: I added an image that shows the exception hope that helps

Comment: If, instead of working directly with UI elements, you use Bindings (as is customary for WPF), then you will not need a "manual" conversion and, accordingly, there will be no exceptions.
Learn how to work properly with WPF and you will greatly facilitate your work.

Comment: When faced with a problem like this, it is always easiest if you do all the converting into separate variables one at a time.  That way you can step through the code line by line  to check on which value it fails.  It would then be a simple matter to check wht the text value is, which causes the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `System.FormatException` happens when you want to "parse" a string to another type, like an integer, that makes a number in text be represented as a real number, in your case, you are calling `Convert.ToInt32`, be sure that whatever string being passed as argument to this method, don't overflow the capabilities of the `Int32` struct, or that the text does not contain letters or decimal points. If that is the case, to verify if a number is valid use `int.TryParse`, it will only return true if the text is in a correct format like so:

```cs
if (int.TryParse("5", out int number))
{
    // Do something with that number
}
```

Here, if "5" is not a number, the if block will be completely skipped.

Comment: note, it also happens when you want to format that in a different way, but this "way" is not valid.